# @cuda.jit(device=True) returns 'DeviceFunctionTemplate' object is not callable

Tags: cuda, numba

I'm working on math method and to reduce execution time I use numba decorator

```py
@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True) 
def analize_tick(data:np.array, index:int, result_signal:np.array) -> None:
   ##I perform an action here and then return result  
   result_sirnal[0]=1
```

it works OK, but when I changed the decorator from `@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True)`  to `@cuda.jit(device=True)` I got the error: *'DeviceFunctionTemplate' object is not callable*
Could you advice me how to fix this issue?
BTW the method recieves three arguments:

- numpy 2 dimensional float array
- int index
- numpy 1 dimensional int array where I return result

---

*UPDATED to add code sample:*

```py
import unittest

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import cuda


@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True) 
# @cuda.jit(device=True)
def calculate(data:np.array, index:int, options:np.array, result_signal:np.array) -> None:        
    i = data[0]
    b = data[1]
    result_signal[0]= i+b

@numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True) 
# @cuda.jit(device=True)
def for_each(data:np.array,options:np.array, result:np.array) -> None:            
    for index, r in enumerate(data):        
        calculate(r, index, options, result)
        # print(result[0])

class cuda_test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_numba_call(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2]], columns=['c0', 'c1'])
        data = df.to_numpy()
        result = np.array([0], dtype=float)
        options = np.array([0], dtype=float)
        for sigma in range(0, 10, 1):
            options[0] = sigma
            for_each(data, options, result)
```

Comment: If you make that into a device function, it can only be called from inside another `@cuda.jit` function. It would be much simpler if you posted a complete example and not a description of it. What you think is important or not isn't necessary what is needed to help you

Comment: hi @talonmies thanks for answer, I've just added code to the post, and did them as much simplest as I can.

Answer (score 2):

> Could you advice me how to fix this issue?

There is no way to fix this. What you are trying to do is impossible.

When you decorate a function like this:

```
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def for_each(data:np.array,options:np.array, result:np.array) -> None:            
    for index, r in enumerate(data):        
        calculate(r, index, options, result)
```

you are [denoting that the function is only available to be called by CUDA kernels or other device functions](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/device-functions.html). You are not calling it within a CUDA kernel or device function. There is no way to change this behaviour, it is a limitation of the language.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I think I understood